# created 4 columns with as command, now need to add all 4 columns

Tags: sql, excel, excel-external-data

I am referencing a rather complex database into excel using sql. There is one table that has 4 rows per instance and I have managed to make them 4 columns on the same instance in my excel table using:

Max( case when(table1.column1 = 'a') Then table1.column2 Else 0 End) as [A],

Max( case when(table1.column1 = 'b') Then table1.column2 Else 0 End) as [B],

Max( case when(table1.column1 = 'c') Then table1.column2  Else 0 End) as [C],

Max( case when(table1.column1 = 'd') Then table1.column2 Else 0 End) as [D]

in the SELECT portion of the code.

Now I need to add the values from all 4 created columns into a 5th column that I can reference but I keep running into issues. I originally just tried 
Total = 'A' + 'B' + 'C' + 'D' 
But that just gave me a text column with "ABCD" in every row instead of adding the values in the columns. I have verified the values in the created columns are numbers.

I am basically looking for a way to use column names created with the AS command in other columns as part of a formula.

Comment: What happens if you use `A+B+C+D` without the single quote around each letter? OR `[A]+[B]+[C]+[D]`... I don't know if that will work, but I'm curious.

Comment: A+B+C+D as 'Total' gives me a syntax error around the +.
And using the [ ] around them gives me Invalid column name 'A'
Invalid column name 'B'
Invalid column name 'C'
Invalid column name 'D'

Answer (score 0):

Two ways, short and long.

Short one:

```
SUM(table.column2) as 5thElement
```

Long one:

```
Max( case when(table1.column1 = 'a') Then table1.column2 Else 0 End) +
Max( case when(table1.column1 = 'b') Then table1.column2 Else 0 End) +
Max( case when(table1.column1 = 'c') Then table1.column2 Else 0 End) +
Max( case when(table1.column1 = 'd') Then table1.column2 Else 0 End)
```

Good luck!

Comment: So the short one doesn't throw an error but the values it gives me are way off from what they should be.
And the long one keeps giving me Syntax errors around the + signs...

Comment: Share whole query, please.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out...

Total = (Max( case when(table1.column1 = 'a') Then table1.column2 Else 0 End)) + (Max( case when(table1.column1 = 'b') Then table1.column2  Else 0 End)) + (Max( case when(table1.column1  = 'c') Then table1.column2 Else 0 End)) + (Max( case when(table1.column1 = 'd') Then table1.column2 Else 0 End))

I just had to remove the 4 AS commands naming the new columns since I'm not actually trying to include the column names in the equation. Thanks for your help guys!